# SQL Server : Update Flag on Max Date on Foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I'm trying to do this update but for some reason I cannot quite master SQL sub queries.

My table structure is as follows:

```
 id  fk    date     activeFlg
---  --  -------    ---------
 1   1   04/10/11      0
 2   1   02/05/99      0
 3   2   09/10/11      0
 4   3   11/28/11      0
 5   3   12/25/98      0
```

Ideally I would like to set the activeFlg to 1 for all of the distinct foreign keys with the most recent date. For instance after running my query id 1,3 and 4 will have an active flag set to one.

The closest thing I came up with was a query returning all of the max dates for each distinct fk:

```
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY fk
```

But since I cant even come up with the subquery there is no way I can proceed :/

Can somebody please give me some insight on this. I'm trying to really learn more about sub queries so an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the fk to and then restrict by that, so

```
SELECT fk,MAX(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY fk
```

To

```
With Ones2update AS
(
  SELECT fk,MAX(date)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY fk
)
Update table
  set Active=1
from table t
join Ones2update u ON t.fk = u.fk and t.date = u.date
```

also I would test first so do this query first

```
With Ones2update AS
(
  SELECT fk,MAX(date)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY fk
)
selct fk, date, active 
from table t
join Ones2update u ON t.fk = u.fk and t.date = u.date
```

to make sure you are getting what you expect and I did not make any typos.

Additional note:  I use a join instead of a sub-query -- they are logically the same but I always find joins to be clearer (once I got used to using joins).  Depending on the optimizer they can be faster.

Comment: Thank you! Not only did you give me the answer but you explained your logic. I wasn't aware of the `WITH` keyword, but it seems to make the query alittle more human readable!

Comment: Yes, WITH is relatively new in SQL.  It can do other interesting things (recursion) but I find it very nice way to develop queries.  If you have a lot of "sub-queries", it can make testing easier because you can just query any point in the chain without changing the rest (just comment out the final query and put what you want there.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea.  You can flesh out the details.

```
update t
set activeFlg = 1
from yourTable t
join (
select id, max([date] maxdate
from TheForeignKeyTable
group by [date]
)  sq on t.fk = sq.id and t.[date] = maxdate
```

Comment: This was the correct answer as well, but Hogan's answer was the "accepted" answer for the explanation. Thank you!